# Make Windows 10 ignore the first keyboard input on wake-up?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, sleep, wake-up

My laptop is set to turn off the screen after a very short duration of inactivity to save battery. On a touchscreen laptop you could just tap the screen to wake the laptop up.

My laptop doesn't have touchscreen and the only way to wake the screen up is by **pressing some key** or moving the mouse (which doesn't always work).

I got used to pressing the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to wake the screen, and the problem is when I'm on a word document **an unwanted space is added** due to the spacebar being pressed to wake the screen.

How can I make Windows 10 **ignore the first key** (*any key*) that is being pressed (to wake the screen) so that it won't affect any window that is open currently?

EDIT: I am aware of the fact that pressing another button like the ctrl or the arrows may not affect the focused window. This is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Interesting question, I always hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for this exact reason!

Comment: @djsmiley2k is right. The easiest way is to choose a different key to press. I use the arrow keys on my computer.

Comment: @MosheKatz I am aware of that, did a little research before asking this question. I'm looking for a solution for every key (atleast the spacebar).